# Distributive Algebra w/o Additive Inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose we are working in an algebra $\left( X, +, \ast \right)$.  Both binary operators are associative and commutative, and $\ast$ distributes over $+$.  However, not all of the elements have an additive inverse (e.g. there is no $B \neq 0$ such that $A+B=0$).

Is this a sufficient condition to show that all elements (except for $0, 1$) cannot have a multiplicative inverse?  If so, how do I go about proving it?  I haven't found any counterexamples so far, and my attempted proofs are going nowhere.

EDIT:

I suppose I should have clarified that there is a total ordering on $X$, such that if $S= \{ x \in X : x \leq C \}$ for any element $C$, then $|S|$ is finite.  I will define the ordering such that $A+B \geq A$. I am only interested in cases where |X| is infinite.

Comment: Do you mean no elements (apart from $0$) have an additive inverse, or that not all elements do? And do you mean no multiplicative inverse for all non-zero elements, or for some (otherwise, the naturals will be a counter example)?

Comment: Only $0$ has an additive inverse.  And I am trying to show that it is impossible for every non-zero element to have a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: The non-negative rationals is a counterexample then.

Comment: Oh, I feel really stupid for overlooking that. I suppose I should add the condition that there is a total ordering on X, and that if $S = \{ x \in X : x < C \}$ for some constant element C, then |S| is finite.

Comment: I'm confused. Do we also have an underlying ring somewhere, or are we simply dealing with a semiring?

Comment: @JonathanY. $X$ is simply a semiring.  I've made an edit to the original post to clarify some conditions I left unstated.

Comment: Are you ensuring that the ordering respects the second operation at all?

Comment: Well then, perhaps editing to refer to $X$ as a semiring (as well as mentioning that no non-zero element should have an additive inverse) would be clearer still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All non-zero numbers are positive because $a=a+0\ge 0$ and $a\ne0$ implies $a>0$.
Then $a+b=0$ implies $a=b=0$, i.e. only $0$ has an additive inverse.
We shall assume that $1\ne0$.

Define the map $f\colon \mathbb N\to X$ recursively per $f(1)=1>0$ and $f(n+1)=f(n)+1>0$. Assume all nonzero elements of $X$ have an inverse. For $n\in\mathbb N$, let $a_n$ be an inverse of $f(n)$, i.e. $1=a_n\cdot f(n)=\underbrace{a_n+\ldots +a_n}_n$.
Then $1=\underbrace{a_n+\ldots+a_n}_n\ge a_n$ and from the finiteness of $\{\,x\in X\mid x\le 1\,\}$ we conclude that there is some $a$ such that $a_n=a$ for infinitely many $n$.
Let $n$ be minimal with $a_n=a$ and let $m>n$ with $a_m=a$.
Then 
$$1=\underbrace{a+\ldots +a}_m= \underbrace{a+\ldots +a}_n+\underbrace{a+\ldots +a}_{m-n}=1+\underbrace{a+\ldots +a}_{m-n}\ge 1+a$$
implies $a+1=1$ and $a\cdot f(m)=1$ for all $m\ge n$.

If we had cancellation, then $a+1=1$ would imply $a=0$ and then $1=\underbrace{a_n+\ldots +a_n}_{n}=0$, contradiction.

Therefore, there exists $0\ne a\in X$ with $a+1=1$. Note that $a\le 1$ and by the above we may assume $a\cdot f(n)=1$ for some $n\ge1$.
Then $a^2f(n)=a$ and $a^2f(n^2)=1$. Thus if $a\ne1$ we also have $a^2<a$ and by repeated squaring we find an infinie decreasing sequence of positive numbres, contradicting the fact that $\{\,x\in X\mid x\le 1\,\}$ is finite.
Therefore $a=1$ and $$1+1=1.$$

Comment: Hmm, so are you assuming that there are no elements between $0$ and $1$.?  Is there a loss of generality by assuming this?